# creating bat file that connects to sql

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that connects to MySql and run a script file.  It works doing it manually in CMD.  The batch file runs until the password stage.  Then it does n'ot continue even if I put the password in the batch file.  Here is a copy of what I am putting into notepad.

```
cd\
cd Program Files
cd Mysql
cd Mysql Server 5.7
cd bin
mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1
"*password*"
use "*database to run script on*";
\. *scriptfile*.sql
```

Could someone please advise me how I should write this so it automatically inputs the password and continues to run the script file?

Ps: the really strange thing is I actually got it to work at first. It was working fine, then all of a sudden it stopped at the password.

Comment: Why aren't you putting the password after the `-p` option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch script to issue commands to mySQL db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755939/batch-script-to-issue-commands-to-mysql-db)

Comment: thanks guys i got it passed the password by putting password after "-p". so now it connects to mysql but stops there the following commands dont execute. " use "database name" then ".\ scriptfile.sql"

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it working by using the tips in the comments. Thanks for all your help.

This is what I have in the batch file now:

```
cd /D "C:\Program Files\Mysql\Mysql Server 5.7\bin"
mysql.exe -uroot -pPASSWORD -h127.0.0.1 -DDATABASENAME <SCRIPTFILE.sql
```